# Старший бит числа 0 в двоичном представлении

Tags: типы-данных

Почему при кодировании числа 0, он записывается именно как положительный 0, т.е. 0.0000000? А не, допустим, отрицательный (со старшим битом равным 1 - 1.0000000).
Рассматриваются целочисленные типы данных со знаком.

Исторические предпосылки? Или это связано с выполнением арифметических опеоаций в двоичном виде?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Потому что отрицательные числа представлены не в [прямом коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), а в [дополнительном](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)).

А ещё потому, что существуют беззнаковые типы, и весьма логично, что в неотрицательной части они совместимы.

Comment: ... но имеют право быть представлены и в прямом, и в любом другом удобном разработчику языка. Например, в JavaScript вообще нету целых чисел.

Comment: @VladD 1. Цитируешь Си++? Если не ошибаюсь, в C# представление прописано в спецификации.
2. В джаваскрипте есть целые числа. Любые битовые операции работают с signed int 32. `Math.pow(2,32)!==0 && ~~Math.pow(2,32)===0`

Comment: Хм, в C# вполне может быть, это в их духе. А C/C++ любят бежать на кофеварках и тостерах, там и количество бит в байте не гарантированно 8, и битовое представление `nullptr` не гарантировано все нули.

Comment: Ну, в js может быть они и есть где-то в качестве промежуточного результата, но по факту такого _типа данных_ нет, ЕМНИП. Соответственно, и битового представления в дополнительном коде — тоже.

Comment: @VladD, `nullptr` же всегда 0. Иначе бы они сломали совместимость кода.

Comment: Не всегда. http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Comment: @VladD, это, конечно, верно и поэтому разработчики C++ на всякий случай не стали уточнять чему равен nullptr. / Однако, я абсолютно не верю, что кому-то в обозримом будущем придет в голову реализовать архитектуру (на машинном уровне) в которой не будет работать nullptr === 0 (именно из-за совместимости с кучей существующего кода)

Comment: @avp: А чему это может помешать? Каст `NULL` в `int` обязан в любом случае давать 0, чему бы ни был `NULL` по факту равен. Вот union и прямой доступ к битам, это да.

Comment: @VladD, memset с нулём. И вообще, любой memset, ибо он байты копирует, а не 4- или 8-байтные указатели.

Comment: @VladD, да есть много кода, используещего  calloc и memset для инициализации. Так что все нулевые биты тоже должны восприниматься как nullptr (иначе перенос ПО станет дороговат)

Comment: @avp: Я, кстати, именно по этой причине никогда не использовал `memset`. Если с нулевым указателем всё более-менее понятно, то что с `enum { val = 1 }`? Что с `double` (да, там всё хорошо, но это не самоочевидно)? Что с указателями на методы классов?

Comment: @VladD, наверное для правильного кода  на C++ (и C# ?) memset не особо и нужен. Ведь там классы, соответственно конструктор работает.

Comment: @VladD, да, классы нельзя обнулять memset'ом - там указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций может быть. А вот массив указателей - ооочень хочется :)

Comment: @avp, C# сам обнуляет выделенную память. Но ему-то как раз ненулевой null не страшен - jit-компилятор разберётся, если что.

Comment: @avp: В C# есть value types (это структуры, которые можно копировать побитно), у них гарантировано есть валидное default-значение, соответствующее всем нулевым битам. А с классами, да, нельзя (но язык и не даст).

Comment: @VladD, если очень постараться, то даст... В unsafe-коде по-любому даст.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, массив указателей можно просто `T* arr[] = {};`

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это да, в unsafe-коде можно сделать любое UB. Но на это он и unsafe, и им по уму никто не пользуется, кроме старшего архитектора системы.

Comment: @VladD, я имел в виду динамический. malloc или new, потом memset. Хотя да, массив нулевух указателей - это немного не самая полезная штуковина. Но и не бессмысленная. Для какого-нибудь кеша сгодиться может.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А если так: [`T** arr = new T*[100]()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030018/276994)? C++ — язык с непредсказуемым синтаксисом.

Comment: @VladD, не знал :) Но ведь эта штука всё равно нули запишет? Или именно нулевые указатели? Кстати, а с предыдущим примером (T* arr[] = {};) не так же?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Оно выполнит конструктор по умолчанию, который пропишет правильные с точки зрения системы `nullptr`'ы. Прописать именно нулевые байты не так просто. :) Хотя, конечно, `memset` (и `reinterpret_cast`) умеет всё.

Comment: @Qwertiy, т.е. это связано с тем, что целочисленный отрицательный ноль не может быть представлен в дополнительном коде (в котором хранятся и обрабатываются отрицательные числа), я правильно понял? А в дополнительном мы не можем записать, т.к. при добавлении единицы к обратному будет переполнение?

Comment: @Dima346753, да.

Comment: @VladD, Qwerty, может быть перенесете полезную информацию из комментариев в ответ?

Answer (score 3):

Это зависит от платформы и представлении в ней целых чисел. Некоторые платформы поддерживают во внутреннем представлении целых чисел отрицательный ноль.

Из стандарта языка C (6.2.6.2 Integer types):

2. ...In the case of sign and magnitude and ones’ complement, if this representation is a normal value it is called a **negative zero**.

> 3 If the implementation supports negative zeros, they shall be
>   generated only by:

```
— the &, |, ^, ~, <<, and >> operators with operands that produce such a value;
— the +, -, *, /, and % operators where one operand is a negative zero and the result is zero;
— compound assignment operators based on the above cases.
```

> It is unspecified whether these cases actually generate a negative
>   zero or a normal zero, and whether a negative zero becomes a normal
>   zero when stored in an object.

Просто самые распространенные платформы имеют внутреннее представление целых чисел в виде дополнения до 2^n, для которого либо представление, в котором знаковый бит установлен, а все другие биты равны нулю не является допустимым значением (trap value), либо является отрицательным числом.